# Transaction Pending 5 days

Tags: gas-price, pending-transactions

`0xdb651909881589110a34e4ec28691a367d6b0edd62f73268dbf6b569150b50d3`

The above transaction has been pending for 5 days, low gas I guess,
I sent to ether delta to make sure address was correct,before further deposit.
This is obviously blocking further transactions,
What can I Do? Sent via metamask but transaction history not showing it, only on etherscan, IF I had history I could probably pay extra gas,
MEW has a offline tx generator, can I open a mew wallet via mew and over write this transaction with higher gas same nonce,,Thanks

Comment: Hi there. The gas price is too low for that transaction to go through any time soon (given current market conditions). You'll need to resubmit the transaction with a higher gas price and the same nonce.